# require.resolve not finding file even though fs can

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm having a problem with node.js `require.resolve` the method that makes no sense having with the test I'm running first.

So my Code

```
let checkPluginCanLoad = (pluginName, pluginFile) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        // build the plugin's class files path
        console.log(`looking for file at ${path}/${pluginName}/${pluginFile}`)
        let req = `${path}/${pluginName}/${pluginFile}`
        // check it exists blocking
        let fileState = fs.existsSync(`${req}.js`);
        if(fileState){
            console.log(`File ${req}.js ${fileState?"exists.":"does not exist."}`);
            // it exists try to load it
            let plugin = require.resolve(`${req}`);
            res(plugin);
         }else{
            // could not find or load the plugin
            rej(`Plugin is invalid can't find or load class for ${pluginFile}`);
        }
    });
}
```

The vars are set to , `path = "Plugins", pluginName = "TestPlugin", pluginFile = "TestPlugin";`

My output is

```
Plugins from 'Plugins' have been loaded.    index.js:36 
looking for file at Plugins/TestPlugin/TestPlugin   Plugins.js:133 
File Plugins/TestPlugin/TestPlugin.js exists.    Plugins.js:138 failed to
load plugin 'TestPlugin' with error 'Error: Cannot find module  'Plugins/TestPlugin/TestPlugin''
```

The final line
`load plugin 'TestPlugin' ...` comes from the system above this one catching the rejection.

So the file Exists according to `FileSystem` but the resolver can't find it.

I have tried prepending it with `../` before the path in case it's resolving from the file that is running it and not the application directory, 
I have also tried prepending it with `./` in case it's running it from the application directory.

Comment: Why are you using a promise if you are not doing anything asynchronous?

Comment: I am higher up the trace there is aync function containing the call to this all the plugins are loaded async. so it can load them all them all at once. plugins are the last thing to load after about 5 other systems that get injected into the plugins that all load async. then the plugin loader starts loading multiple plugins asynchronously. it also means the plugins can do asyn stuff when they start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a bug caused by symlinks on windows with junctioned directories,

So for my dev environment it junctions the directories from my Git Repository directory. but Node is running it through the junction directory but seeing the original directory.

E.G
Git repo is in `D:\Projects\NodeAppRepo`
then the dev environment is running inside `D:\Project\NodeApp\`
I have `index.js, Core/, node_modules/` all running via a junction inside the NodeApp to the paths in the git repo.

so i'm running `node index.js` inside `D:\Project\NodeApp\` wich is in turn loading `D:\Project\NodeApp\Core\Core.js` this then imports `./Plugins.js` this is where the break happens because the path node has for plugins is not `D:\Project\NodeApp\Core\Plugins.js` it is `D:\Projects\NodeAppRepo\Core\Plugin.js`

Answer (score 2):

you need to add `./` to tell node that you are targeting local file.

```
let plugin = require.resolve(`./${req}`);
```

if you forgot node will search in [steps described here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules)

Comment: Please read my last paragraph, for example node is running `index.js` in dir `/app/ ` this file the code is from is in the path `/app/Core/`. so I have tried both `./` and `../` i have even now tested `./../`

Comment: strange, I've tried it on my machine and it's working fine.
what about explicitly specifying extension `.js`.

Comment: I have used it a few times and never had a problem like this with it.